# Install DISLIN library in Python - Ubuntu

Tags: python, python-3.x

I followed all the recommendations of the READ ME from DISLIN documentation, but I still have this problem every time I try to import it in Python:

```
from dislin import *
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in  ImportError: No module named
>   dislin

Comment: Unless you show the steps you took to install DISLIN and its Python binding, we can't really help you.

Comment: I downloaded dislin, unzipped and tried the command ./INSTALL to install it, but I had this output: The environment is not defined!